# Can we start studying number theory before abstract algebra?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, soft-question

I have started studying elementary number theory independently.
 I was wondering that is it necessary to first finish abstract algebra

Comment: It's not necessary at all, lots of people learn elementary number theory first.

Comment: Very few subjects cannot be learned without first "finishing" another subject. So, no.

Answer (score 4):

A mastery of abstract algebra is by no means necessary to learn elementary number theory. In fact, I've found that the concepts in elementary number theory really motivate a lot of the concepts in abstract algebra. Once you get to the point where you've gone through and learned a good deal of elementary number theory, you may, however, find that you have a lot of interesting questions that are best answered in the language of abstract algebra (e.g. regarding reciprocity laws, unique factorization domains, etc.). But I'd say you should get started and not worry about those trickier questions until you ask them.