# Should one study number theory before studying abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, soft-question

My question is the opposite of the question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816689/can-we-start-studying-number-theory-before-abstract-algebra).

I have started studying abstract algebra independently. I'm wondering if it is necessary, or at least advised, to have studied elementary number theory prior to studying abstract algebra, say at the level of Dummit and Foote's *Abstract Algebra* or Knapp's *Basic Algebra*.

Comment: There are plenty of non-number-theory topics to which to apply abstract algebra. Most applications of abstract algebra have no obvious connection to number theory. Examples books may use from number theory will probably require only very basic prerequisites which will likely be recalled unless the book is about algebraic number theory specifically, but then it will recall a lot more. One of the earliest forms of what would become group theory was Galois' work on solutions to polynomials which wasn't really number theoretic.

Comment: Some number theory basics are a prerequisite to abstract algebra. Things such as the division algorithm, Beźout's identity, primes, etc. From personal experience, I found number theory to be delightful and I thought I had greater insight into the subject after taking a full course in both group and ring theory.

Comment: It is related to the [choice of rings-first vs. groups-first](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/10478/rings-before-groups-in-abstract-algebra) presentations of abstract algebra. Which approach does your textbook use?

Comment: @BillDubuque Groups first.

Answer (score 7):

It's a good question. The fact is, the subjects are interdependent. For Abstract Algebra, you need *some* amount of Number Theory basics, else the motivation for many of the concepts will be lacking. Conversely, without some Abstract Algebra, certain Number Theory concepts appear more mysterious than they should be.

My recommendation: If you don't already have the early Number Theory knowledge, self-study a few chapters from a Number Theory text, preferably *before* taking Abstract Algebra. As a minimum, acquire the basic knowledge relating to divisibility, primes, and congruences, at least up to Fermat's little Theorem and Euler's generalization.

Answer (score 0):

Certainly not necessary.  It might help somewhat as it provides some of the standard examples.